# Почему переменная из окружения равна none?

Tags: python

В конфигурациях pycharm добавлен .env файл, где прописаны URL и TOKEN_KEY
в директории 1 лежит py file config.py:

```
import os
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class CommonConfig:
    url: str = os.getenv("URL")
    token_key: str = os.getenv("TOKEN_KEY")
```

при print(CommonConfig.url) выводится значение из файла .env

Но при обращении к этим переменным из py файла, лежащего в другой директории, их значение становится None:

```
from ... import CommonConfig

class TestAuth:

    def test_request(self):
        print(CommonConfig.url) #None
```

Верно ли понимаю, что передается дефолтное значение os.getenv? А как получить значение этой переменной из env?

Comment: А сам файл `.env` в каком каталоге лежит?

Comment: .env лежит в корне